# replace cryptoJS with PHP function

Tags: php, mcrypt, cryptojs

Just to cut it short. Is there an equivalent script for the code below. I tried using mcrypt but the IV output seems different in crypto and in mcrypt.

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may be useful: [Javascript equivalents of PHP encode / decode routines](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/). I have not tried them

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not an encryption algorithm, but an encoding one. As such, it is not part of MCrypt ... and that wouldn't be necessary anyway. What you need is the `base64_decode()` function.